# Radius of convergence of $1 + \frac {x^1} {1} + \frac {x^2} {2} + \frac {x^3} {3} + \dots$

Tags: power-series

Can someone please help me to compute the radius of convergence of

$$1 + \frac {x^1} {1} + \frac {x^2} {2} + \frac {x^3} {3} + \dots ?$$

Comment: I have tried to correct your MathJax formatting, please check whether my edit has preserved the intended meaning.

Comment: Yes Alax you are right I am new on this site can you please tell me how you corrected it so I will not do this mistake again

Comment: The history of edits is available by clicking on the "edited ... ago" link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your series is
$\sum a_n x^n$

with $a_n=\frac{1}{n}>0$

$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=$

1.

which is the inverse of convergence radius.

your radius is $1$

Comment: What happens if the sign of series alters for this that is first term is positive, second term negative and so on

Comment: you compute limit of $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|$ to obtain the inverse if $R$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $R=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{1/n}{1/(n+1)}\right|=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{n+1}{n}\right|=1$