# How to find number of subgroups of given order in the group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose G is a group that has exactly eight elements of order 3. How many subgroups of order 3  does G have?.I know that the order of an element as well as the order of subgroup divides the order of the group.  But I am not able to apply the logic here.

Comment: Do not completely alter your questions! Ask a new one instead.

Comment: Stop editing this question to ask new ones.

Comment: I want to do the same but the site is not accepting my questions. I am a new user on this site and one of my question was heavily down voted. What should I do so that I can ask new questions again please suggest.

Comment: It's a temporary block. At the moment, you can only wait until it expires next week. To avoid further blocks, provide some context to your questions in future. Questions that consist of a bare problem statement, like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968474/radius-of-convergence-of-1-frac-x1-1-frac-x2-2-frac-x3-3) tend to attract downvotes. If you had for example said something about what you know of computing the radius of convergence of a power series (do you know the ratio test or the root test? the Cauchy-Hadamard formula?) it would be less likely to attract downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mapping $g\mapsto \langle g\rangle$ from elements of order $3$ to the subgroups they generate is a 2-to-1 mapping from the set of elements of order $3$ onto the set of subgroups of order $3$. So, if you have a 2-to-1 mapping of an 8-element set onto a second set, how big must the second set be?

Edit: I respond to a comment:

If $g$ has order $3$, then $\langle g\rangle = \{1, g, g^{-1}\}$. Under the mapping that assigns an element $g$ to the subgroup it generates, both $g$ and $g^{-1}$ get assigned the subgroup $\langle g\rangle$,
and these are the only elements that get assigned this subgroup. Hence the mapping is 2-to-1 from the set of elements of order 3 to the set of subgroups of order 3.

Comment: It should be 4 according to your suggestion

Comment: That is correct!

Comment: But I am not able to clearly followed the logic with which you defined the mapping as 2 to 1 .can you elaborate it?